# How to print the file slowly?

Tags: linux, shell, file, unix, cat

I am in the course of preparing a presentation and I want a file to be printed on the screen s l o w l y, while I am commenting on it. Typing `cat file.txt | less` seems to be an obvious solution but is there another one, more elegant and pleasing to eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -ne '$|=1; for (split //) { print; select(undef,undef,undef, 0.15) }' file.txt
```

`$|=1` do not buffer.

`for (split //) { print;` ...for every character printed...

`select(undef,undef,undef, 0.15)` sleep 0.15 seconds (You can change this value according to your taste and needs).